# incompatible pointer type warning in c?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

```
uint32 measurements [32];

Xcp_Addr_t XcpApp_ConvertAddress( uint32 address, uint8 extension )
{

    return &measurements[address];  //return from incompatible pointer type 

}
```

address is the value which i am recieving from the client (example : 0,1,2.....). The above function as to return the address of the measurement to the other internal function. I am getting a warning as below :

```
return from incompatible pointer type
```

could anyone tell me how to solve this ?

Comment: What's the typedef of `Xcp_Addr_t`?

Comment: typedef uint8* Xcp_Addr_t;

Comment: well then, `uint8_t*` is not the same as `uint32_t*` - there you have your reason I guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the type of `Xcp_Addr_t`. Your expression is: `&measurements[address]`. The type of the expression is convertible to `uint32*`. If your return type is an `uint32` in disguise, then just remove the `&` operator. If your return type is completely different, you are to rethink what you are doing.

---

So your typedef is:

```
typedef uint8* Xcp_Addr_t;
```

as you can see `uint8*` (of the return type) and `uint32*` (the actually returned value's type) don't match. You can either change the return type or the type of the array `measurements` to:

```
uint8 measurements[32];
```

---

Ok, so you want to ensure that `XcpApp_ConvertAddress` returns a valid pointer (without going out of bounds). You have two choices:

- assert it
- throw an exception

You can assert it by doing:

```
assert(address < 32);
return &measurements[address];
```

in this case the program will fail at runtime if the address passed to the function is incorrect (notice that you have to add `#include <cassert>` to use `assert`).

Alternatively you can throw an exception:

```
if (address < 32) throw std::runtime_error("out of bounds");
return &measurements[address];
```

(notice that you'll need `#include <stdexcept>` for `std::runtime_error`).

Comment: it should be uint8 measurements[32];

Comment: You may also want to check that `address < 32` before returning; otherwise you perform an out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: Xcp_Addr_t XcpApp_ConvertAddress( uint32 address, uint8 extension )
{
    /* TODO: review this implementation */
int i;
    /* Assume that no conversion is required. */
 for(i=0; i<=31; i++)
 {
    return &measurements[address];
 }
}

Comment: @user3383557, you are always going to return the first element's pointer.

Comment: if(address < 32) return &measurents[address];

Comment: if(address < 32) return &measurents[address]; then It is throwing one more warning : control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: @user3383557, yes, because in case `address` is `>= 32` what should it return?

Comment: if address > 32 then it should return nothing.could you give me a example ??

Comment: @user3383557, you can't return nothing if the return type is `uint8*`. That's the whole point of the type system in C++. Let me write a solution for you.

Comment: could you give me a c example ??

Comment: @user3383557, use the first example with `assert` and include `<assert.h>` instead of `<cassert>`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to decide if you want to return the value of  `measurements[address]` or its pointer !

Comment: I want to return the address of measurements

Comment: so declare your variable 'Xcp_Addr_t' like 'typedef uint8* Xcp_Addr_t;'

Comment: @Anis_Stack Please add your code part as part of the answer.